# How can I name a value by calling a character value?

Tags: r, character, names

I wish to gives values in a vector names. I know how to do that but in this case I have many names and many values, both within vectors within lists, and typing them by hand would by suicide.

This method:

```
> values <- c('jessica' = 1, 'jones' = 2)
> values
jessica   jones 
      1       2
```

obviously works. However, this method:

```
> names <- c('jessica', 'jones')
> values <- c(names[1] = 1, names[2] = 2)
Error: unexpected '=' in "values <- c(names[1] ="
```

Well... I cannot understand why R refuses to read these as pure characters to assign them as names.

I realize I can create `values` and `names` separately and then assign `names` as `names(values)` but again, my actual case is far more complex. But really I would just like to know why this particular issue occurs.

EDIT I: The ACTUAL data I have is a list of vectors, each is a different combination of amounts of ingredients, and then a giant vector of ingredient names. I cannot just set the name vector as names, because the individual names need to be placed by hand.

EDIT II: Example of my data structure.

```
ingredients <- c('ing1', 'ing2', 'ing3', 'ing4') # this vector is much longer in reality

amounts <- list(c('ing1' = 1, 'ing2' = 2, 'ing4' = 3),
                c('ing2' = 2, 'ing3' = 3),
                c('ing1' = 12, 'ing2' = 4, 'ing3' = 3),
                c('ing1' = 1, 'ing2' = 1, 'ing3' = 2, 'ing4' = 5))
            # this list too is much longer
```

I could type each numeric value's name individually as presented, but there are many more, and so I tried instead to input the likes of:

```
c(ingredients[1] = 1, ingredients[2] = 2, ingredients[4] = 3)
```

But this throws an error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "amounts <- list(c(ingredients[1] ="
```

Comment: But since you say *"within vectors within lists"*, perhaps it would be better to know the structure of these "lists". Can you provide a representative sample of the lists, either programmatically `list(...)` or with `dput(head(l))` (where there is not much more to the lists that we don't need to know).

Comment: I edited in a concrete example.

Comment: How do you know for instance that `ingredients` 1, 2, and 4 are applied to a particular vector within `amounts`? There doesn't appear to be a solid pattern.

Comment: There isn't one, this is data I need to construct from hand written notes for an exercise I'm making. Honestly I don't know why it even matters, this issue is present even for normal vectors, I'm looking for why the error happens. What does it matter where the `amounts` come from?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm lost. If there isn't a way to know for certain which ingredients (names) should be applied to which members of a vector *in human words*, then how do you expect there to be a function to do it for you? The error happens because R (nor most other languages I know) do not build vectors in precisely that way, but more precisely: you can do `ingred[1] = "a"` and you can do `c("ingred" = 1)`, but you cannot do `c(ingred[1] = 1)`, it is a parsing error, R cannot do it. ...

Comment: While you might try to force the issue (using `parse`, for instance) define a string and then reassign components within the string and then parse it into an R command and evaluate it, this is prone to so many errors and flaws and is about is anti-idiomatic as you can get (in R). Sorry, what you want just ain't easy given your constraints.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setNames`

```
setNames(1:2, names)
```

---

Another option is `deframe` if we have a two column dataset

```
library(tibble)
tibble(names, val = 1:2) %>% 
     deframe
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood so I added an explanation to the question. Although I specifically stated that I cannot do what you suggest, which is an equivalent of just doing `names(values) <- names`, because there are multiple values in different places with the same name,

Comment: @Ronny Efronny please post some sample data using `dput()`. Otherwise, It would be hard to help you.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny. How is the `amounts` relatedd to the `ingredients`?  Not clear from your posst